# GetElementById equivalant in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div>
    <input id="txt"  type="text" placeholder="Choose File" />
    <input type="file" id="selectedFile" class="hidden" onchange="ChangeText(this, 'txt');" />
    <span>
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();">Browse</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

I just want that on-click event in angular js. Can anyone tell?

I just want that on-click event in angular js.
Can anyone tell?
code is in comment

Comment: <div>
                <input id="txt"  type="text" placeholder="Choose File" />
                <input type="file" id="selectedFile" class="hidden" onchange="ChangeText(this, 'txt');" />
                <span>
                    <button type="button"  onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();">Browse</button>
                </span>
            </div>

Comment: Please discribe the problem more clearly. If u want click event in angular then need to use ngclick event

Comment: My code is in js, in that for browse button I have given onclick event so that it wil fetch selectedfile id element like this,                                                 <input type="file" id="selectedFile" class="hidden" onchange="ChangeText(this, 'txt');" />
                <span>
                    <button type="button"  onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();">Browse</button>                                                                                                           so I want that function in angular js

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: I dont want to use document.getElementById in the angular js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, before I might not have read your question fully. Now I have, and I think this is what you're looking for: https://plnkr.co/edit/pfjU5B17qCzwHKoG4iTN?p=preview

```
.controller('Upload', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    this.input;

    this.browse = function() {
        this.input.click();
    };
}])
.directive('fileUpload', [function() {
    return {
        'restrict':'E',
        'controller':'Upload',
        'controllerAs':'upload',
        'templateUrl': './upload.html',
        'link':function($scope, $element, $attribute, upload) {
            upload.input = $element.find('input')[1];
        }
    };
}]);
```

In the link-function of the directive I injected the input into the controller. The controller simply fires a click-event into the node, thus calling the file-browser.

**edit**: I would personally not use an input to show the file, but show a more generic listing of all selected files, with a preview if possible. That way you simply have to use the first input :)

Sorry for not reading your question better, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the angular way, the DOM should call functions in your code, not your code polling for events in the DOM.

```
<script>
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    doTheThing();
  });
</script>
<button id="btn">Do the thing!</button>
```

versus

```
<my-button  ng-click="{{ MyBtnCtrl.doTheThing() }}">Do the thing!</my-button>
```

with a Controller

```
function MyButtonController() {
  this.doTheThing = function() {
    alert('I\'m doing the thing!')
  };
}
```

edit:
As I now only see your code, the code you showed is not angular-code. If you want to use angular, check out these links:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial
- https://www.codeschool.com/pages/angular-1-vs-2

I prefer the codeschool to get you started, as it's more interactive and provides a step by step guide.

Comment: Instead of getElementById, What can I write in inside the function for angular js

Comment: You don't. You should write a directive with a controller, and simply call the functions of the controller from within your DOM. When using angular you should "never" use a DOMNode in your code. There might be some exceptions, but always aim to not reference your DOM in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <input id="txt"  type="text" placeholder="Choose File" />
    <input type="file" id="selectedFile" class="hidden" onchange="ChangeText(this, 'txt');" />
    <span>
        <button type="button" onclick="click();">Browse</button>
    </span>
</div>

$scope.click = function() {
        document.getElementById('selectedFile').click()
};
```

Comment: Inside the function your usiing document.getElementById('selectedFile').click().    Can we do the same functionality without using getElementByID